# How to get the next element of an array with Jquery onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

Hi all i am trying to change the html of an object from an array of htmls. But i am having problem iterating properly. I managed to make it work once 
EDIT
After a few complains about the clarity of my question I will rephrase it. I have a div panel called .trpanel and a button called #trigger2 (it is a next button). Then I have a series of divs with texts that contain translations. I want when I press the button (called next) to cycle through the translations one by one on the trpanel.

```
var ltranslation = [];
    ltranslation[0] = $("#translation-en-1").html();
    ltranslation[1] = $("#translation-ur-en").html();
    ltranslation[2] = $("#translation-fr-en").html();
    ltranslation[3] = $("#translation-it-en").html();
    ltranslation[4] = $("#translation-sp-en").html();
    ltranslation[5] = $("#translation-po-en").html();
    ltranslation[6] = $("#translation-fr-en").html();
    ltranslation[7] = $("#translation-de-en").html();

    var l= ltranslation;



   $("#trigger2").off('click').on('click',function(){ 
    for (var i = 0; i <= ltranslation.length; i++){ 
if (i==7){i=0;}
     $(".trpanel").html.ltranslation[i]; or ???//replace().ltranslation[]+i??? the code throws errors  
    } 
    });
```

I am quite new to Javascript and i am getting a bit confused with the  types of objects and arrays and loops. I managed once to add the htmls but without replacing them ... so they all came one after the other. The i tried to change the code and it hasn't worked since. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using `.off('click')` before calling `.on('click')` looks useless in your example. Same goes for `if (i==7){i=0;}` : just change your exit condition in your loop with an exclusive comparator (< instead of <=).

Comment: I use the same #trigger button to do other thing before and with the off I can unbind the previous event handlers. I am not completely sure what Jquery does exactly there but with the off it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of guessing, but seems like you are trying to do this :

```
var trans = $('[id^="translation-"]'),
    idx   = 0;

$("#trigger2").on('click',function(){
    $(".trpanel").html( trans.eq(idx).html() );
    idx = idx > 6 ? 0 : idx+1;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dVQgn/)

Comment: I am trying to change the html every time you press the button. You have a button (called next) and then when you press it see one text after the other. with a reset at the end to start from the beggining.

Comment: @alexnode - Oh, okay, edited the answer, does that work for you ?

Comment: Thank you so much This works. I have to change the startsWith translation with finishesTo english $('[id$="en"]'). There is a bit of weird behaviour though after it finds all english it adds all the other translations there are a lot of translations to other languages too. !!! i don't understand the eq(idx) does it gets all ids and sorts them with ?

Comment: eq() just gets one element out of the elements matching the selector, so eq(0) would get the first etc. and idx is an index, that increases for each click.

Comment: Finally I fixed it, I had a few problems the one was that it idn't work well without on - off ( I used the same button to do other things before) Thank you so much ! eq is exactly what needed. brilliant code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do this:

```
if (i == 7) {
    i = 0; // I don't really know why you are doing this, but it will reset the loop
}
 $(".trpanel").html(ltranslation[i]); //I'm passing ltranslation[i] to the html method. Instead of .html.ltranslation[i].
}
```

Also, without seeing any html, I'm not sure but I think you may want to iterate over `.trpanel` ?

Something like:

```
 $(".trpanel").eq(i).html(ltranslation[i]);
```

Another thing (so you can make your code clearer I think). You can abstract the array population in a function, like this:

```
var ltranslation = [];
var languages = ["en-1", "ur-en", "fr-en", "it-en", "sp-en", "po-en", "fr-en", "de-en"];

$.each(languages, function(index) {
    ltranslation[index] = $("#translation-" + this).html();
});
// Then you can use ltranslation
```

Comment: @alexnode: Your condition has `<=` instead of `<`.

Comment: @alexnode, if that is appearing while calling `ltranslation[i]` it means you aren't defining `ltranslation` correctly and it's `undefined`

Comment: Thank you Nico that works but I accepted the Adeneo post first.Sorry for the badly written question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly you're tring to do, but I've put comments in your code to help you better understand what your code is doing.  The net effect of your code is this (which I doubt you want)  :

```
 $("#trigger2").off('click').on('click',function(){ 
     $(".trpanel").html(ltranslation[7]); 
});
```

This is your code with some comments and minor changes

```
   var ltranslation = [];
    ltranslation[0] = $("#translation-en-1").html();
    ltranslation[1] = $("#translation-ur-en").html();
    ltranslation[2] = $("#translation-fr-en").html();
    ltranslation[3] = $("#translation-it-en").html();
    ltranslation[4] = $("#translation-sp-en").html();
    ltranslation[5] = $("#translation-po-en").html();
    ltranslation[6] = $("#translation-fr-en").html();
    ltranslation[7] = $("#translation-de-en").html();

var l= ltranslation;



   $("#trigger2").off('click').on('click',function(){ 
    for (var i = 0; i < ltranslation.length; i++){ 
     //if (i==7){i=0;}  <-- This will cause an infinite loop won't it?  are you trying to reset i? i will reset next time loop is called,
          $(".trpanel").html(ltranslation[i]);  //<-- this will overwrite elements with class .trpanel ltranslation.length times... 
         ///you'll see only the value of translation[7] in the end
     } 
    });
```

**EDIT**

To do what you want to do based on your comments, try this:

```
 var ltranslation = [];
        ltranslation[0] = $("#translation-en-1").html();
        ltranslation[1] = $("#translation-ur-en").html();
        ltranslation[2] = $("#translation-fr-en").html();
        ltranslation[3] = $("#translation-it-en").html();
        ltranslation[4] = $("#translation-sp-en").html();
        ltranslation[5] = $("#translation-po-en").html();
        ltranslation[6] = $("#translation-fr-en").html();
        ltranslation[7] = $("#translation-de-en").html();
 var counter = 0;//a global counter variable
 $("#trigger2").click(function(){  //eeverytime button is clicked do this
    $(".trpanel").html(ltranslation[counter]); //set the html to an element of array
    counter++;  //increment counter
    if(counter==ltranslation.length) //reset the counter if its bigger than array len
       counter=0;

  });
```

Comment: I am trying to change the html every time you press the button. You have a button (called next) and then when you press it see one text after the other. with a reset at the end to start from the beggining.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to flip through several translations I would implement it that way:

```
var translations=["hej","hello", "hallo","hoy"];

var showTranslation=function(){
    var current=0;
    var len=translations.length;
    return function(){
        var direction=1;
        if (current>=len) current=0;
        $("#text").text(translations[current]);
        current+=direction;
    }
}();

$("#butt").on("click", showTranslation);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xr9fz/

Further: You should give your translations a class, so you could easily grab all of them with a single line:

```
$(".translation).each(function(index,value){ ltranslation.push(value); })
```

Comment: Thanks Thank you Lilith that works but I accepted the Adeneo post first. Sorry for the badly written question.

Answer (score 1):

From the question : *I managed once to add the htmls but without replacing them* -

I think you want to add all of these items into `$(".trpanel")`. First, dont take the HTML of each element, `clone` the element itself :

```
//method ripped from Nico's answer.
var ltranslation = [];
var languages = ["en-1", "ur-en", "fr-en", "it-en", "sp-en", "po-en", "fr-en", "de-en"];

$.each(languages, function(index) {
    ltranslation[index] = $("#translation-" + this).clone();
});
```

Then you could append everything into the container, so *add the htmls but without replacing them*. `append` takes in an array without replacing the previous html.

```
$("#trigger2").off('click').on('click',function() {
    $(".trpanel").append(ltranslation);
});
```

Comment: could i use replace(ltranslation) instead? append will add them all one under the other.

Comment: try `html` instead of `append`